# No answer possible. How do I end the topic with no answers?

Tags: discussion, support, math-se

I asked a question in [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com), but there is no answer in Math to the question I asked (it's still a conjecture). I would like keep the topic for future contributions (not delete it), but I don't want to be penalised because of this. It is a relevant question in math and I can't accept a random answer.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Post an answer that explains that there's no proof (if one hasn't already been posted) and accept that.

However, having an accept rate of less than 100% is nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Thanks. I will quote all users that helped me in that question and close it with my own answer explaining there is no answer available.

Answer (score 8):

Consider leaving it open. You shouldn't be penalized in any way for not closing that question.

Comment: Thanks. But I think better do what ChrisF says...maybe I will be penalized about another users for leave this question open.